# What, if anything, can I do with the "progessive" man in the Lansdowne Residence?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

I'm wandering around in the Lansdowne Residence, and upon reaching the lowest floor, I came across a man who doesn't seem to want to attack me.  He claims to be a "Progressive", whatever that is.

I could shoot him and go through his pockets for loose change, but that seems rude.

**Is there something I'm supposed to do with this guy, or is he just there for scenery?**

Comment: Actually, I shot him (by accident). He didn't carry any loot with him. Later on, I encountered other people like him (who don't attack you on sight), made sure they didn't die, and nothing happened. So, I think they're just scenery. There are also absolutely no mention of those people (not that I can remember) later on in the game, so kill them or let them be, the choice is yours.

Comment: "By accident". _Suuuuure_ it was.

Comment: @Alex *Of course* it was. I was cleaning my gun, when the shot triggered by itself. Not my fault, honest! ;p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This guy is just there for flavor, and I believe he's referring to the fact that he's "for" the Vox Populi.  He's a civilian, and [as I've noted previously](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/110565/is-there-a-reason-for-me-to-not-kill-everything/112355#112355) you can murder civilians with impunity, although they are very unlikely to give you any loot.

Later there is another residence you can pass through with more of these progressives, who appear to be harboring some wounded workers or Vox members.  There's a tutorial popup about "violence" perhaps not being the only answer here.  If you spare these folks, they'll send away a police patrol that knocks on their door after a few seconds.  Otherwise, the police will burst in when they hear shooting or when nobody responds.

However, the police patrol hangs out outside, and you'll have to fight them eventually.  The overall choice here is relatively minor.

Answer (score 4):

> [pro·gres·sive](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%3A+progressive)
>   A person advocating or implementing social reform or new, liberal ideas.

People view you as the false shepard, the man here to destroy their way of life.  When someone says they're a 'progressive,' that just means they support you.

There is nothing special you do with them, they're just there to add to the atmosphere.